# How to check for a valid public IP address?

Tags: ipv4, ip, ip-address

Consider a list of IP addresses as provided by [the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For):

> 10.0.0.142 , 192.168.0.10 , 212.43.234.12 , 54.23.66.43

I would like to know which is the first publicly-accessible address in that list. I can look over them easily enough, but how can I tell which are publicly-accessible? It seems to me (my untrained eye) that `10.0.0.142` is a workstation, `192.168.0.10` is an internal proxy, and `212.43.234.12` is a publicly-accessible address being forwarded through the proxy at `54.23.66.43`. Is there any way to calculate this in code?

My first intuition is that addresses that start with `10.` or `192.` are not publicly accessible, but http://simplesniff.com reveals my home IP address to be `192.117.111.61`. Is there a formula for determining which addresses are public and which are reserved private? Note that even trying to ping the server in question might not help as some servers won't respond to ping, and also there might be an address on my local network which also matched the internal address.

Comment: I would also point out that even *if* you find an address is routable, some companies abuse public address space internally.  I have first-hand knowledge of a very large and well-known corporate name that is inexplicably using [AFRINIC](http://www.afrinic.net/) and AT&T IPv4 space on their internal corporate network instead of RFC1918 space... they proxy all HTTP traffic... and the X-Forwarded-For header from their corporate network will show public space they do not actually own.

Comment: @MikePennington first hand experience of this too, except they were using APNIC numbers. Could also cause an issue when an internal machine (especially those that find the destination to be in their subnet) tries to access one of the public servers...

Comment: @MikePennington - for a private network using puplic IPv4 addresses that are actually in use outside of the private network (ie: the internet), how would someone inside the private network reach a public site with an IP address in that same range? Wouldn't that request be routed to some computer (even perhaps their own computer) within the private network?

Comment: Blindly trusting x-forwarded-for is a *bad* idea. It's trivial for any abuser to set a fake x-forwarded-for header claiming any address they want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

RFC 1918 defines private IP address ranges. Have a look [here.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)

From that document:

3. Private Address Space

   The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
   following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

   10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)

   172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)

   192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)

Comment: Thank you. I find it interesting that `127.0.0.0/16` (and maybe more) are not on that list.

Comment: localhost is defined in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761

Comment: @dotancohen:  The loopback block is a /8, not a /16 and is not on that list because it's not private address space.

Comment: @Blrfl: Thank you, I wasn't sure how wide the loopback block is. I'm actually not looking to identify private addresses but rather non-public addresses (a subset of which is private). Other than the RFC 1918 / 6890 addresses and the 127.0.0.0/8 space, are there other obviously non-public addresses that one might come across?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_use_of_other_reserved_addresses

240.0.0.0 - 254.255.255.254 
(240.0.0.0/4 and 255.0.0.0/8)

Answer (score 38):

Besides the original RFC 1918 space (which is now updated to [RFC6890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)), there are several other blocks such as 192.0.2.0 that are not announced publicly.  Furthermore, it's possible that someone has valid IPv4 space that just isn't announced in the public internet.

The simplest thing to do is `telnet route-views.oregon-ix.net`, login as `rviews` and look for yourself... for instance, this is some "192" space that's announced by AS7018 (AT&T)...

```
route-views>sh ip route 192.199.1.0
Routing entry for 192.199.1.0/24
  Known via "bgp 6447", distance 20, metric 0
  Tag 7018, type external
  Last update from 12.0.1.63 3w1d ago
  Routing Descriptor Blocks:
  * 12.0.1.63, from 12.0.1.63, 3w1d ago
      Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1
      AS Hops 2
      Route tag 7018

route-views>
```

On the other hand, you'll see that 192.0.2.0/24 (ref [RFC6890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)) is nowhere to be found...

```
route-views>sh ip route 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
% Subnet not in table
route-views>
```

Nor is 169.254.0.0/16 (or longer)...

```
route-views>sh ip route 169.254.0.0 255.255.0.0 longer
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 128.223.51.1 to network 0.0.0.0

route-views>
```

Comment: [RFC 1918](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) has not been updated by(or to) RFC 6890. [RFC 6890](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6890) simply "*reiterates the assignment of the IPv4 address block (192.0.0.0/24) to IANA. It also instructs IANA to restructure its IPv4 and IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registries.*" It does not update the IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry Entries for Private-Use and the IPv4 address block 192.0.0.0/24 is categorized as "[IETF Protocol Assignments](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6890#section-2.1)."

Comment: @one.time, RFC 6890 contains a superset of the address space reserved in RFC 1918. I have no idea why you are talking about 192.0.0.0/24; perhaps you should re-read my answer more closely :-)

Comment: the IPv4 block 192.0.0.0/24 is of the main talking points of RFC 6890 so I made reference to it for good measure and comparison to RFC 1918. "Besides the original RFC 1918 space (which is now updated to RFC6890)" is what sparked my curiosity when reading your post. Aside from an update to special-purpose address registry entries for IPv4 and IPv6 for the inclusion of 192.0.0.0.24, RFC 6890 is not an update to RFC 1918. I just wanted to provide an observation regarding the accuracy of the statement. HTHs ;-)

Comment: @one.time, pedantically RFC 6890 is not an update to RFC 1918.  Functionally, one should use RFC 6890 instead of RFC 1918 when considering IP space that is valid in a public BGP table...

Answer (score 14):

**[Team Cymru](https://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/)** provides a bogon reference for both IPv4 and IPv6 that you can use to filter out unassigned/reserved/private IP addresses - it's offered both as a simple list for well-known prefixes and also in a much larger list that includes space that is as-yet unassigned by RIRs.

They also run a BGP bogon server that you can request a free peering to - invaluable if you're unable to run a default-free zone to the internet.

Comment: Frankly 'unassigned' is something that is useless to filter, filtering it causes lot more problems than it solves. And actual bogons are easy, as they are very stable/static.

Comment: OK, then don't use that one, As I said, they offer a variety of flavours.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ranges that are reserved for various use cases. IANA has the authoritative and [comprehensive list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml). It includes RFC1918, RFC6761 as well as more recent reservations like the 100.64/10 CGN block. If you find any addresses in there they are likely somehow used in a private network and should be discarded in favour of the others in search of the first public address.